# Undo committed changes

Tags: git, branch, git-commit, git-revert

I learn from a book, called Ryan Hodson - Ry's Git Tutorial, and it says:

> Before we undo the changes, we need to return to the master branch. If we didn’t, all of our updates would be on some non-existent branch. You should never make changes directly to a previous revision.

What does it mean?

In my case, I'm at the tip of the `master` branch, and i have to revert to the previous commit

Comment: `revert` has a specific meaning in git.  To revert a commit is to create a new commit that undoes the first (eg, it's a reverse patch).  If you want to revert the previous commit, just do `git revert HEAD`.  This is different than throwing away the previous commit (which is essentially "rewriting history", and your author is advising against that.  That advice is debatable).  What do you want to do?

Comment: @WilliamPursell - I don't think the tutorial is commenting on revert vs. rewrite (at last, not in this passage).  It seems to be warning against committing while in detached HEAD, though it's not 100% clear without more context.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger - Your assumption is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most clearly written passage IMO; but after a couple re-reads, I'm pretty sure I've inferred the correct context to understand what it means.  (It's the only conceptually-accurate way I can find to interpret this passage, so...)

Presumably if you've been following the tutorial step by step, then you are currently in "detached `HEAD` state".  This occurs when you directly check out a commit - usually because you've checked out a commit further back in your branch's history.  For example if you have

```
A -- B -- C <--(master)
```

and you checkout the `B` commit, by saying something like

```
git checkout master^
```

then this puts you in detached `HEAD` state.  You could represent this as

```
A -- B -- C <--(master)
     ^
    (HEAD)
```

It looks like the tutorial leads you to do this to examine a change, which it now determines you want to undo.

So it's saying that if you *don't* first checkout master, and you make another commit, you'll end up with

```
A -- B -- C <--(master)
      \
       D 
       ^
       (HEAD)
```

You'd still be in detached `HEAD` state, and `D` would not be "reachable" from any ref.  This isn't *always* wrong (as the tutorial suggests), but it isn't typically right.  You'd have to take further steps to prevent `D` from just getting discarded.

The tutorial uses the phrase "make changes directly to a previous revision", but that's not a precisely accurate description of what you'd be doing.  It would be more accurate to say that you typically would avoid staging new changes while in detached `HEAD` state (but probably the author finds that phrasing too technical/confusing for git novices).

Comment: Good intuition!

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger - `D` is a **dangling commit** in your example, right? Anyway, thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes, that is sometimes the term that's used.  And what that implies is, once you move `HEAD` away from `D`, and once the reflog entry for when `HEAD` was at `D` expires, `D` becomes eligible for garbage collection. (Unless, in the intervening time, you do something to make `D` reachable.)